# Redirect Subdomain to internal server

Tags: linux, macos, mac

I have an Apache server in home connected to a router that only allow 1 server on port 80. Everything is working fine, but now I have one Mac Mini Server that is configured to use port 80.

How can I redirect an sub-domain from my main server to an internal IP address (Mac Mini server)?

The main server's IP is `10.0.0.73` and that of the Mac Mini is `10.0.0.82`. Is that possible?

I tried to use proxy but i dont know if it is well configured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache to proxy requests for you other domain, create a virtual host that responds to the subdomain and then sends the requests to your mac.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName    subdomain.lan
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://ip.ad.re.ss/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://ip.ad.re.ss/
        ProxyErrorOverride Off
        ErrorDocument 404 /notavail.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is a disgusting solution (`mod_proxy` sucks!), but it also happens to be the right one given the constraints above.

Comment: @Iain Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work in my setup and i dont know why. I can access my mac server in local network via ip address or via subdomain (if in mac server) but not for other computers on lan network.